# Math.cos() gives wrong results

Tags: javascript

According to my understanding, and my calculator, `cos(90 degrees)` equals `0`.
In my code, I have a function that allows me to type in degrees whenever I need to:

```
function deg(i)
{
    return i*Math.PI/180;
}
```

Although, when calling `Math.cos(deg(90));` the output I receive is `6.123233995736766e-17`.

Why could such a thing possibly happen?

(Please excuse me for my bad English)

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: [`What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @adeneo Thank you, that really IS it, how do I mark my post a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deg(90)` is *approximately* equal to `90*Math.PI/180` and your result is *aproximately* equal to `0`.

So, everything is fine ;)

*Note that it has to be approximate, because there is no way to represent π precisely.*

Comment: a little over `6` isn't really approximately equal to zero?

Comment: @adeneo, `a little over 6 `? `6.123233995736766e-17` is so very much far away from 6. That's `6 * 10 ^ -17`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - there could at least be a little explanation on scientific notation ?

Comment: Well, I obviously wouldn't mind a value very close to 0 instead of actual 0, but could you please explain whether `6.123233995736766e-17` is closer to 0 or 6?

Comment: @adeneo, this is standard scientific notation. There's no need of further explanation.

Comment: @adeneo 6.123233995736766e-17 is 0.00000000000000006123233995736766

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I know that, but I'm guessing not everyone does, nor do they know why javascript, and other languages, don't calculate correctly.

Comment: Just saying it's "approximate" doesn't seem like a very good answer to me, but it seems I'm wrong.

Comment: @adeneo, that's why in my comment I have linked to an article about  
`What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic` : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html So that they don't be confused.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - and that's why I in my comment have linked to a question that actually answers this question. And yes, I've read the article you've linked to a long time ago